# nginx: [emerg] open() "/www/server/nginx/conf/enable-php.conf" failed

Tags: php, nginx

ERROR: An error was detected in the configuration file. Please solve it before proceeding

nginx: [emerg] open() "/www/server/nginx/conf/enable-php.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /www/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:68
nginx: configuration file /www/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

AAPanel with Apache

While Adding new Site it's give this error

Answer (score -2):

Just run this command and try again:

`touch /www/server/nginx/conf/enable-php.conf`

Comment: Assuming that the problem is not that there is _supposed_ to be a file there and have actual _content_.

Comment: I have the same issue and fixed it by running the same  command

Comment: "Removing the error message" is not necessarily the same as fixing the issue.